# Good framework for text editing in web app (Angular/Rails web app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, text-editor

First of all, sorry for not having programming related questions, but StackOverflow was the only website to ask these!

Im building a web app. I am using Angular for front-end and Rails for backend. I put my front-end inside of my Rails app, so they are in a same project now.

I am currently looking for a good & simple text editor for my web app now.

Functionalities I'm looking for:

1. Retrieve a template letter from my project file system(meaning I will have a default template letter in my web app) to the text-editor in front-end.
2. Edit the template letter using text-editor and save the change.
3. Saved changes should be saved in a new word file format in the file system. This means that there will be 2 files: a default template letter and newly edited letter file).
4. All files should be saved in Word file.
5. I'm not looking for text-editor with rich functionalities but minimum level like (Making text bold, aligning text, making a list etc, change the font color)

Is there a good framework out there for this purposes? I found bunch of text editors but not perfectly good for my purpose!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you gem 'ckeditor'.

Comment: Can you use this for free? I do not really how do I install this.

Comment: Yes, it is free. The instruction for implementing this editor to your app is  [here](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails)